# renderRequest attributes are always null after calling renderURL

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, liferay, portlet

I can't seem to access data I want to pass to my .jsp files. I've simplified it to the bare-bones and it still doesn't work for me. This portlet is being deployed to a liferay portal.

Problem: I click on the link to call a renderURL for the next .jsp page. In the doView() method, I set an attribute with setAttribute. When I retrieve that attribute in the .jsp, it returns null.

Expected output: "Proper Value"

Actual output: "Default value"

**NewPortlet.java (Controller)**

```
public class NewPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
            throws IOException, PortletException {
        request.setAttribute("test", "Proper Value");
        String path = ParamUtil
                .getString(request, "path", "/html/new/view.jsp");
        include(path, request, response);
    }
}
```

**view.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:renderURL var="testURL">
    <portlet:param name="path" value="/html/new/edit.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
<p><a href="<%= testURL %>">Click me!</a></p>
```

**edit.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<%
String test = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "test", "default value");
%>
<p><%= test %></p>
```

Comment: Well, you are setting an attribute in doView method and getting parameter in jsp. It will certainly return you null as there wont be any parameter set named as test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exact usecase you have.

But here issue is, you are setting attribute and trying to fetch parameter, hence it returns null.

For solution to your issues as in code, use `renderRequest.getAttribute("test")` or use el, `${test}`

Comment: thank you, this is why an extra pair of eyes is always helpful.. once you stare at your code long enough these kinds of errors become invisible

Answer (score 1):

The "view.jsp" is referring "edit.jsp" using `portlet:renderURL` and that can be an issue. `The render requests may be executed sequentially or in parallel without any guaranteed order.`

I am not sure why your workflow is this way (i.e. setting parameter in doView method), but try actionURL instead of renderURL.

Comment: While this wasn't the problem, thanks for bringing this up. I will use an actionURL